# AngularJS Modal Dialog with File Upload Control not working

Tags: angularjs, modal-dialog

I am using  AngularJS Modal Service. http://fundoo-solutions.github.io/angularjs-modal-service/

I setup it in a simple way

Button to open a Model

```
<div data-ng-controller="contest as vm">
   <a class="btn btn-primary" data-ng-click="vm.createFileUploadDialog()">Upload Image</a>
</div>
```

Inisde Controller I have a function defined createFileUploadDialog and expose it from my viewModel.

```
 vm.createFileUploadDialog = createFileUploadDialog;
   vm.uploadme = {};
   vm.uploadme.src = "";

 function createFileUploadDialog() {

            createDialog('/app/templates/fileuploadDialog.html', {
                id: 'filuploadDialog',
                title: 'Upload Contest Image',
                backdrop: true,
                success: { label: 'Upload', fn: uploadSuccess },
                cancel: { label: 'Cancel' },
            });
}

function uploadSuccess() {
     console.log(vm.uploadme);
         //need to call to the backend        
}
```

And inside "fileUploadDialog.html" I have a simple markup

```
<div>
 <input type="file" fileread="uploadme.src" />
</div>
```

"fileread" is a directive which return back the src of the File. Now the problem I have

As you can see I am doing console.log inside "**UploadSuccess**", in response I am getting the result `"Object {src: ""}",`

It looks like the Modal values not capture inside controller. But If I do the same with `$rootScope`, it logs out the File that need to upload. So, how can I access the value without using `$rootScope`? Please suggest

PS:
I am not define separate controller for Modal, want to use the same controller that treats my view.

Comment: can you pls show your `uploadme.src` code as I need that. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

** Modals scope is not the same as your controller scope!**

if you want to see your Controller scope inside of your modal and manupulate it , you're gonna have to use **resolve** inside of your modal markap like this :

```
           createDialog('/app/templates/fileuploadDialog.html', {
            id: 'filuploadDialog',
            title: 'Upload Contest Image',
            backdrop: true,
            success: { label: 'Upload', fn: uploadSuccess },
            cancel: { label: 'Cancel' },
             resolve:{
               controllerscope:function(){
                return $scope;
            }
        }
        });
```

And now , inside of your modal controller you can inject :** controllerscope ** and use it , also data binding works well like this :

```
        app.controller('modalcontroller',function($scope,controllerscope){
           // no you have access to your controller scope with **controllerscope**
         })
```

So go and have a look at your modal plug in wich you are using and search for *resolve* and *controller*

thats it

Comment: Thank you very much. Defining the separate controller for a Modal works great.